# Get filename before download

Tags: android, download-manager

I want to download some files using my own webview, but when i use download manager i am not able to get the default name of the file before downloading it.

I tried this but it does not work

```
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName );
```

Any ideas?

What you need:

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url2) {


            if(url2.startsWith("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=")){


            if(isDownloadManagerAvailable(MainActivity.this)){


                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url2));


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }


                request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);


//Get file name as string


                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, -----);//put it here


                manager.enqueue(request);




            }
            }
            else{
                view.loadUrl(url2);

                }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I think you can also use Uri.getLastPathSegment() : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getLastPathSegment() . not sure about it though. Anyway, what does the variable "url" and "fileName" equal to?

Comment: Because url is not like http://www. ........../audio.mp3     that's why it cannot find the name of file

Comment: What is the URL value then? And can a web browser (for example) know what is the file name when you try to download it from there?

Comment: Yes,  Es file downloader can.

Comment: have you tried "URLUtil.guessFileName()" ?

Comment: No, and actually now i am from mobile. Post it as answer and i will try later...

Comment: Thing is that I'm not sure it works. If it works, please let me know and I will put it as an answer. There might be other possible solutions that I didn't find yet.

Comment: Please show the Url that you are trying out. Maybe I'll try it myself.

Comment: http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=128&video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&h=1c1f479c948bb9cfb495605c7214cb49&r=1407775588334.1531971212

Comment: well it's not a file... it's just a webpage... or maybe you want the HTML file of it?

Comment: Np my friend is a file but i cannot get the url of that file as my webview

Comment: You mean after you click the "download" link ?

Comment: interesting... gonna try to solve this. hope I succeed. do you have any sample project to start from?

Comment: do you want to show you my code?

Comment: could be useful. you don't have to... if it's too irrelevant , don't put it.

Comment: see my edits hope that helps

Comment: I've posted a sample that shows that guessFileName does work and can get you the file name of the url (at least in this case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use something like this (maybe less code is needed) :

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
      {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        final WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
          {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view,final String url)
              {
              return false;
              }
          });
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
          {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(final String url,final String userAgent,final String contentDisposition,final String mimetype,final long contentLength)
              {
              final String fileName=URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype);
              android.util.Log.d("Applog","fileName:"+fileName);
              // start downloading:
            //  final Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
           //   startActivity(i);


  DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }


            request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);





            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);


            manager.enqueue(request); 
              }
          });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
          {});
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=128&video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&h=1c1f479c948bb9cfb495605c7214cb49&r=1407775588334.1531971212");
        }
      }
```

Comment: From what I saw in server logs this solution actually triggers 2 call on same URL on server: one is made before entering  onDownloadStart(...) method and the second is made by manager.enqueue(...)  :(

Comment: This is very helps me:
 final String fileName=URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype);

Comment: this is not working for me. returning a messed up file name which causes file not to be saved

Comment: @easazade It depends on what it gets. Its function is named as "guessFileName" for a reason... It doesn't guarantee anything... What is the input you get from there, that you see that it gets messed up?